# English word for something that satisfies several constraints

Tags: meaning

So, is there an english word for this?

Comment: You might get more answers if you gave us a little more to work with. Can you provide an example or a sentence you would use the word in?

Answer (score 3):

> **optimal**
>
> *adjective*
>
> Best or most favorable; optimum: seeking the optimal solution
>   <sub>[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/optimal)</sub>

If you need a more precise mathematical definition, the solution that satisfies several mathematical constraints is often not a single optimal point but a set of points narrowed down from a solution space or feasible set by a process called optimization.

> **Optimum / Mathematical optimization**
>
> In mathematics, computer science, operations research, mathematical
>   optimization (alternatively, optimization or mathematical programming)
>   is the selection of a best element (with regard to some criteria) from
>   some set of available alternatives.[1](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/optimal) In the simplest case, an
>   optimization problem consists of maximizing or minimizing a real
>   function by systematically choosing input values from within an
>   allowed set and computing the value of the function. The
>   generalization of optimization theory and techniques to other
>   formulations comprises a large area of applied mathematics. More
>   generally, optimization includes finding "best available" values of
>   some objective function given a defined domain (or a set of
>   constraints), including a variety of different types of objective
>   functions and different types of domains.
>   <sub>[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_optimization)</sub>